# fullpage.js slider. problems with absolute blocks. Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I have a problem with slider controls and any block with position: absolute on slider section.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
});
```

```css
.slide { 
  text-align: center
}
.section {
  text-align: center;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide1 {
  background: #cccccc;
}
.slide2 {
  background: #C3C3C3;
}

.section2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fullpage/2.5.9/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.fullpage/2.5.0/jquery.fullPage.min.css" />
  <div id="fullpage">
      <div class="section section1">
        <div class="absolute">position: absolute</div>
        <div class="slide slide1"> Slide 1 </div>
        <div class="slide slide2"> Slide 2 </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section section2">Some section</div>
  </div>
```

If you slide down and up - everything is ok. But if you use slider and then will slide down and up. The page will show without slider controls(and absolute block).

I can't find why it is happening. Problems occurs only in Chrome and Opera.

**UPDATES:**
Here is jsfiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/nfL5w9yL/1/

Comment: Add a reproduction in codepen or jsfiddle and you'll get more chances of getting answers.

Comment: I've tried to put plunker, but it says that I should use code snippet for it.

Comment: You can as long as you add code to the question. But I'm talking about codepen.io or jsfiddle.net in any case

Comment: added jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/nfL5w9yL/1/

Comment: Can you describe your problem in other way? I dont understand when you say "But if you use slider and then will slide down and up. The page will show without slider controls(and absolute block)."

Answer (score 0):

Fullpage adds z-index:1 to fp-slides
Had the same issue recently, i don't know if you found a solution, but my solution was to remove z-index from fp-slides!

the weird part is that in my case the navigation buttons were not affected, only my position absolute div